# Probability question for 5 independent requests for two different groups

Tags: probability

There are $8$ web servers across two clusters that host a bank’s website ($4$ servers in USA-West and $4$ servers in USA-East).

If we assume that transactions from a given IP/location will always go to a particular cluster, then a transaction will go to one of $4$ servers (i.e., there is a $1/4$ chance of any server getting a particular transaction).

Assume a user completes $5$ independent requests sequentially. What is the probability that a user/IP’s transaction will occur on the same web server for those $5$ requests?

## My attempt

- the query always go to one cluster
- in one cluster there are $4$ servers
- prob $= (1/4)^5$

This looks straight forward question and I guess it might be a trick question. I am looking answers from statisticians.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your $(1/4)^5$ is too low - that is the probability they all go to a particular server, but ignores the possibility they all go to another single server.  (All assuming which server in the cluster is chosen each time uniformly and independently  of the other transactions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of where in the United States the individual lives, there are four web servers available to her.  The probability that all five transactions go to a particular one of those four servers is
$$\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^5$$
as Henry pointed out in the comments.  However, there are four web servers available to her, so the probability that all five of her transactions are sent to the same web server is
$$4 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^5 = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4 = \frac{1}{256}$$
Another way to see this is that her first transaction must be sent to some web server.  The probability that a subsequent transaction is sent to the same web server is $1/4$.  Hence, the probability that each of the five transactions is sent to the same web server is
$$1 \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{256}$$